# Problem in scraping specific part of a website

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am looking at this website https://www.bcassessment.ca//Property/Info/QTAwMDAwMVYyUA== and am looking for the most up to date price listed on the website. I want to extract this price from the website body using `rvest` package. To do this I had a look at the html code for the website:
[image]

Following the instruction I saw for `rvest` package, I used the code shown below:

```
library(rvest)
a <- read_html('https://www.bcassessment.ca//Property/Info/QTAwMDAwMVYyUA==')
b <- a %>% html_nodes('div class="total-value"') %>% 
  html_text()
b
```

However, this will result in an error: `Error in parse_simple_selector(stream) : Expected selector, got <DELIM '=' at 10>`. I also tried this code:

```
library(rvest)
a <- read_html('https://www.bcassessment.ca//Property/Info/QTAwMDAwMVYyUA==')
b <- a %>% html_nodes("span") %>% 
  html_text()
b
```

However, this gave me more than 50 results in which I can find the total price. How can I specifically choose the total price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the tag where the value is stored.

```
library(rvest)

url <- 'https://www.bcassessment.ca//Property/Info/QTAwMDAwMVYyUA=='
url %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_nodes('span#lblTotalAssessedValue') %>%
  html_text()

#[1] "$380,900"
```

You can use `readr::parse_number()` to change the above value to numeric.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain how this works? so basically you defined the next leaf in html by adding `#lblTotalAssessedValue`?

Comment: To refer the id we use `#` symbol. So here I am selecting `span` tag whose `id` is `lblTotalAssessedValue`. To specify class you can mention it via `.`. something like `span.class_name`.